# Making Kotlin Suspend Function Cancellable

Tags: kotlin

I want to make a suspend function cancellable, but `isActive` isn't accessible. Is this just handled automatically?

```
suspend fun coolFunction() {
    while (isActive) {
        /* Do cool stuff */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cooperate with cancellation, you can periodically suspend, most simply done by calling `yield()`

```
suspend fun coolFunction() {
    while (true) {
        yield()
        /* Do cool stuff */
    }
}
```

You can also support cancellation by checking `CoroutineScope.isActive`. But a suspend function on its own doesn't have direct access to the CoroutineScope it was called from. You would have to use something like `coroutineContext[Job]!!.isActive`, which is clumsy. `isActive` is more useful when you're directly composing a coroutine with something like `launch` rather than a `suspend` function that could be called from any scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the job or coroutineScope that suspending function is running in so the suspending function will cancel.

```
private suspend fun CoroutineScope.cancelComputation() {

    println("cancelComputation()")

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var nextPrintTime = startTime
        var i = 0

        // WARNING  isActive is an extension property that is available inside
        // the code of coroutine via CoroutineScope object.

        while (isActive) { // cancellable computation loop
            // print a message twice a second
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                println("I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
                nextPrintTime += 500L
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
    job.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion println("main: Now I can quit.")

    /*
        Prints:
        cancelComputation()
        I'm sleeping 0 ...
        I'm sleeping 1 ...
        I'm sleeping 2 ...
        main: I'm tired of waiting!
     */

}
```

Comment: How does the function cancel though? What if it has some open resources that it should close? Does it just crash and burn when the job is cancelled?

Comment: Official documents are one of the best you can learn how coroutines work, [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html) you can check it out, and i suggest learning `flow`after coroutins if  you are interested with reactive programming.

Comment: I've looked at the official docs, they don't really tell me what I want to know. For example, they say the built in functions like `delay` will throw a cancellation exception when its coroutine is canceled. So how does that function know when it's canceled? That's basically what I wan to know. `flow` isn't really applicable I don't think. My function(s) do a potentially long running process and then return a single value.

Comment: If you are working with resources, you need to use try-finally or `Closeable.use` as usual so it will clean up the resources if cancelled.

Comment: So it will skip to finally if it's canceled? The official docs indicate that a loop that doesn't check for cancellation will continue forever (or at least until the loop ends naturally).

Comment: Yes, as Tenfour04 stated you need to check out with `yield` or use launch block to check out if it's active if you are inside a loop. I'm addin loop snippet with launch to my answer

Comment: It won't automatically skip to `finally` once it's cancelled. The function has to have a suspend point to have an opportunity to be cancelled. Then it will go to `finally` if the job is cancelled before or during the suspension.